# Calculate total column for each row from a file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have file with the content like this :

```
1.000000 - 1.000200 0 -> 2 A-MPDU 1.000000 - 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 - 1.000200 FAIL 
1.000225 - 1.000270 2 -> 0 ACK SUCCESS [01]
1.000425 1 TIMEOUT
1.000270 - 1.000570 0 BACKOFF
```

1.How to calculate the total number of column for each line? for example : total_column_row[1] = 15, etc

2.Then, how to make index x for each row to make condition as below? :

```
if total_column_row[x] == 15
   something
elseif total_column_row[x] == 9
   something
elseif ......
```

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)

Assumption : Your file text is saved into array `myTextArray`

```
temp = strsplit(myTextArray, \n)

For ii = 1 to length(temp)

myColRows(ii) = length(strsplit(temp(ii), " "))

End
```

myColRows has the number of columns per row.

Comment: May I know, what is myTextRows? is it actually myTextArray? and when I use strsplit it said "Undefined function 'strsplit' for input arguments of type 'char'."

Comment: Sorry, it was suppose to be `temp`. I edited my answer accordingly